# Reference Chartview to created view

Tags: swift, uikit, bar-chart

I started to work with Charts in Swift. I have the following code to create a bar chart with random values.
On my storyboard I have created a "View" with the name "AverageView" - type `UIView!`.
Now I want to reference the chart to the created AverageView, means that the chart lies on the view and change automatically the width and height when changing the AverageView.

```
private func createChart() {
    //Create bar chart
    let barChart = BarChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: AverageView.frame.size.width, height: AverageView.frame.size.width))

    //Supply data
    var entries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
    for x in 0..<10 {
        entries.append(
            BarChartDataEntry(
                x: Double(x),
                y: Double.random(in: 0...30)
            )
        )
    }

    let set = BarChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: "Average")
    set.colors = [NSUIColor.gray]
    let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set)

    barChart.data = data
    AverageView.addSubview(barChart)
    barChart.center = AverageView.center
```

I think I must change the line with `letbarChart = BarChartView(frame:...))` or the second last  line: `AverageView.addSubview(barChart)` in the way like `AverageView = bartChart`, but with that expression I see no Chart on the Storyboard.

What is the right code to reference the chart on the created AverageView?

Comment: Use auto-layout constraints instead of setting the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you constrain your barChart view to your AverageView:

```
private func createChart() {
    //Create bar chart
    // frame doesn't matter here
    let barChart = BarChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: AverageView.frame.size.width, height: AverageView.frame.size.width))

    //Supply data
    var entries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
    for x in 0..<10 {
        entries.append(
            BarChartDataEntry(
                x: Double(x),
                y: Double.random(in: 0...30)
            )
        )
    }

    let set = BarChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: "Average")
    set.colors = [NSUIColor.gray]
    let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set)

    barChart.data = data

    barChart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    AverageView.addSubview(barChart)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        barChart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: AverageView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        barChart.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: AverageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        barChart.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: AverageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        barChart.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: AverageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
    ])
}
```

If you want a little "padding" around the bar chart view, change the `constant` values. The **top** and **leading** constants need to be *positive* values, **trailing** and **bottom** need to be *negative*.

So, for example:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        barChart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: AverageView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
        barChart.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: AverageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
        barChart.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: AverageView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        barChart.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: AverageView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
    ])
```

Will "inset" the barChart view by 8-points on all 4 sides.

Comment: Dear @DonMag, thank you very much for your detailed answer and the code. It works perfectly. 
I found another solution, therefore I switched the outlet from the View to BarChartView! and I only add short code after the this line
barChart.data = data
-> AverageView.data = data